# Upper bound on hessian

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives

Given a smooth Riemannian manifold $(\mathcal{M},g)$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathcal{M})$ let $r(x)= d(x,x_0)$ where $d$ is the distance function wrt $g$ and $x_0$ is some point on the manifold. If we have an upper bound on the Hessian, i.e. $\nabla_i \nabla_j f \leq Cg_{ij}$, then we have the following estimate for $f$
\begin{equation}
f(x) \leq C_1 (r(x) + C_2)^2 
\end{equation}
for some constants $C_1, C_2$.

I am unsure how to go about proving this fully. Heuristically this is something like the second derivative test but I can't think of precisely how we bring $r(x)$ into the mix.

Comment: if $M$ is complete try this: for any $x\in M$, draw the shortest path c(t) between $x$ and $x_0$, $f$ constrained on c is a single variable function then you can apply the second derivative test.